# RichTextBox empty when appending from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Whenever I try to log something to my richTextBox with my own `Debug.Log("Text");`, the box stays empty.

I have created a test class to see what was happening:

```
class test
{
    public static void printToConsole()
    {
        Debug.Log("test123");
    }
}
```

and called the method when the windows form was shown:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.printToConsole();
}
```

Debug Class:

```
class Debug
    {
        public static void Log(string text, string c = "White", bool date = true)
        {
            Color color = Color.FromName(c);

            using (Form1 myForm = new Form1())
            {
                if (date)
                {
                    myForm.consoleTextbox.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("[h:mm:ss tt] "));
                }
                myForm.consoleTextbox.SelectionColor = color;
                myForm.consoleTextbox.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);

                myForm.consoleTextbox.SelectionStart = myForm.consoleTextbox.TextLength;
                myForm.consoleTextbox.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Thank you for the answers. I apologize for asking a stupid question and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: dude, you're creating a new Form1() every time you call Log()... you should pass a reference of your form to the Log function: `Log(Form1 myForm, string text, ...`, remove `using (Form1 ...`

Comment: ...or pass just the instance of the RichTextBox control you want to use. So, in Form1, you can call it as: `Debug.Log(this.consoleTextbox, "Some text");`, in Form2: `Debug.Log(this.consoleTextbox, "Some text");`. Oops, it's the same :)

Comment: Declare the method as: `public static void Log(RichTextBox txBox, string text, string c = "White", bool date = true) {  txBox.SelectionColor = color; (...) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in here:

```
using (Form1 myForm = new Form1())
```

You are actually creating a new `Form1` and appending all the text to its TextBox.
You can also get the form as parameter:

```
 public static void Log(Form frm, string text, string c = "White", bool date = true)
 {
      Color color = Color.FromName(c);

      if (date)
      {
          frm.consoleTextbox.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("[h:mm:ss tt] "));
      }
      frm.consoleTextbox.SelectionColor = color;
      frm.consoleTextbox.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);

      frm.consoleTextbox.SelectionStart = myForm.consoleTextbox.TextLength;
      frm.consoleTextbox.ScrollToCaret();

 }
```

Comment: ...but you'll limit that method to only work with a class of type `Form1`, which contains a control named `consoleTextbox`. Seems frustrating :)

Comment: I was just setting an example, it can accept any forms (if they have a richtextbox with that name). I changed the code

Comment: My comment was primarily directed to the OP. Anyway, the modified code wouldn't compile: a generic `Form` class doesn't have a `consoleTextbox` child control. That's why I suggested to pass the Control reference directly: you don't need to know or reference the Parent, it can be any RichTextBox control, child of any Form instance.